# Why do not bind to the properties Width and Height of Canvas?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

Why do not bind to the properties Width and Height of Canvas?

I tried to do it like that, but it did not .

```
  <ItemsControl
                Grid.Row="0"
                ItemsSource="{Binding RectItems}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                //does not work
                        <Canvas Height="{Binding PanelHeight, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                Width="{Binding PanelWidth, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                        <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X}" />
                        <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y}" />
                    </Style>
                </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Rectangle
                            Width="{Binding Width}"
                            Height="{Binding Height}"
                            Fill="Black" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Where do these Properties `PanelHeight` and `PanelWidth` come from

Comment: @lokusking, Properties defined in ViewModel, http://pastebin.com/EqUg8NXr

Comment: As usual, `INotifyPropertyChanged` is missing

Comment: @lokusking, `INotifyPropertyChanged` not solve the problem . The data is not transmitted to any of the parties .

Answer (score 0):

Those bindings seem to work just fine; just add

```
Background="Red"
```

to the definition of Canvas so that you can SEE the actual Canvas.

Answer (score 0):

I've made you an example:

**Classes**

```
 public class RectItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private int _width;
        private int _height;
        private int _x;
        private int _y;

        public Brush Color { get; set; }

        public int Width {
            get { return _width; }
            set {
                if (value == _width) return;
                _width = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public int Height {
            get { return _height; }
            set {
                if (value == _height) return;
                _height = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public int X {
            get { return _x; }
            set {
                if (value == _x) return;
                _x = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public int Y {
            get { return _y; }
            set {
                if (value == _y) return;
                _y = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    internal class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ViewModel()
        {
            this.RectItems.Add(new RectItem { Height = 100, Width = 100, X = 0, Y = 0, Color = Brushes.DeepPink });
            this.RectItems.Add(new RectItem { Height = 50, Width = 50, X = 100, Y = 100, Color = Brushes.DeepSkyBlue });
        }

        private double _panelWidth = 100;
        private double _panelHeight = 100;
        public ObservableCollection<RectItem> RectItems { get; } = new ObservableCollection<RectItem>();


        public ICommand IncreaseSizeCommand => new RelayCommand(x =>
        {
            this.PanelHeight = 200;
            this.PanelWidth = 200;
        });

        public double PanelWidth {
            get { return _panelWidth; }
            set {
                if (value.Equals(_panelWidth)) return;
                _panelWidth = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public double PanelHeight {
            get { return _panelHeight; }
            set {
                if (value.Equals(_panelHeight)) return;
                _panelHeight = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

**XAML**

```
<StackPanel>
            <Button Content="Click me" Width="80" Height="20" Command="{Binding IncreaseSizeCommand}"/>
            <ItemsControl
                Grid.Row="0"
                ItemsSource="{Binding RectItems}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <Canvas Height="{Binding PanelHeight, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                Width="{Binding PanelWidth, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                        <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X}" />
                        <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y}" />
                    </Style>
                </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Rectangle
                            Width="{Binding Width}"
                            Height="{Binding Height}"
                            Fill="{Binding Color}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
</StackPanel>
```

Works as aspected. I've added some colors to do some visual highlighting and a command to change the size of the `Canvas`